# Delegate Instantiate and Invoke Syntax

Tags: c#

Going back to basics - a little confused on the syntax sugar for delegates. Here is my scenario:

I have a delegate which takes zero paramaters and returns void. Essentially an Action delegate with zero parameters. Code snippet below *(purposefully using basic delegate syntax versus Action Delegate usage)*

```
class Program
{
    public delegate void Del(); // Declare
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Del d = MethodCalled;  //Instantiate
        d();   //Invoke

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static void MethodCalled()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello");
    }
}
```

Question: How can I combine instantiate and invocation calls in one sentence (for delegates with no return) similar to below (use-case where I have a return value coming from a Delegate:

```
//Instantiate & Invoke Delegate
string handler = MethodCalled("Hello");
```

*Please note - this question is not how to write a Action Delegate equivalent using Anonymous Method or Lamda Expressions. That I know. Even in there I still have to do invocation of the delegate d(). 
My question is more related to how do i combine 2 statements (irrespective of the syntax used - basic delegate, Action delegate)*

Comment: Why would you ever want to do that?

Comment: Slacks - As mentioned above - this is more of a curious question - if i can do it with return type - when why is there not anything available - atleast I dont know off - for zero value return

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
new SomeDelegate(SomeMethod)(SomeParameter);
```

Comment: Or `new Del(MethodCalled)();` to use the names in the OP's example.